# What relationship do I need?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have `Folder` model, and the problem is, that I want to have `Folder` inside another `Folder`, what relationship can I use in this situation? I thought of adding one more column to Folder model, something like "parentFolderId", is it correct solution in this situation?

Comment: Yes you can use the parent child relationship as explained here https://serversideup.net/eloquent-parent-child-relationship-laravel/

Comment: **Side note:** Some people marked this question as 'needs more focus'. I think the question is complete.  Please retract your votes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table folder

```
* id 
* name
* parent_folder_id
```

Now in the folder model, you can make a hasMany Relation. cause one folder has many folders.

```
function folders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Folder','parent_folder_id','id');
}
```